# How to validate and set errors in recyclerview having multiple edittext?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, material-design

I have a recycler view with multiple edittext and i need to validate each and every edittext before clicking add button and on tapping add button it again creates new edittexts but i need to validate previous edittexts before creating new ones and set errors how to implement this?

[image]

Comment: can you please share the recyclerView adapter code which you're using for adding the EditTexts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add EditText values in array list and validate it when you click on Add Button like

```
val list = arraylistof<EditTextModel>()

add.setonclickListener{

val getItem = list[list.size.minus(1)]// get Last index of list
```

// because when you click add button always check last index because you already //check previous. when you add views on index 1 or index 2.... so on

```
if(getItem.editTextValue1.isEmpty() || getItem.editTextValue2.isEmpty()) {

Log.e("TAG","Edit 1 or Edit 2 may be empty. Please add values")
}

}
```

Comment: And, add these as a method in your adapter class. For example: you can have 2 function in your adapter class validateData() which will contain Vikas's answer and then addView() like you do.

Comment: But how to set errors in edit text layout? How to access it outside view holder class?

Comment: In you Model list you can add EditText reference. Then all will be easy

Comment: How to validate the edit text with text watcher. I have a requirement where if there is no text then red color border , if we type a character , then blue color. Thanks